# Numpy 2d array with float values find the maximum value in a single row and store in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a program that created a numpy array and the array is

> array([[0.0543275 , 0.51249827, 0.43317423],
>          [0.07144389, 0.51152126, 0.41703486],
>          [0.0776112 , 0.48593384, 0.43645496]])

I used the following code for finding the maximum in a row but it is not working for float values

```
for row in a:
maxi = np.argmax(np.max(row, axis=0))
float(maxi)
print(maxi)
```

I want something like this

> array([[0 , 1 , 0],
>          [0 , 1 , 0],
>          [0 , 1 , 0]])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upd: it was originally wrong, now this is just the essence of the the previous correct answer:

```
a = np.array([[0.0543275 , 0.51249827, 0.43317423],
              [0.07144389, 0.51152126, 0.41703486], 
              [0.0776112 , 0.48593384, 0.43645496]])

b = np.zeros_like(a)

b[np.arange(a.shape[0]), np.argmax(a, axis=1)] = 1
```

Since np.argmax() gives us indices of the max elements, we just use them for indexing directly. Now `b` contains desired output:

```
array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

you can also do: `b.astype(int)` to turn to integers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option that works

```
for e, i in enumerate(a):
    for f, j in enumerate(i):
        if j == max(i):
            a[e][f] = 1
        else:
            a[e][f] = 0
```

This will convert the array that you use to the desired form:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [41]: arr = np.array([[0.0543275 , 0.51249827, 0.43317423], [0.07144389, 0.51
    ...: 152126, 0.41703486], [0.0776112 , 0.48593384, 0.43645496]])            
In [42]: arr                                                                    
Out[42]: 
array([[0.0543275 , 0.51249827, 0.43317423],
       [0.07144389, 0.51152126, 0.41703486],
       [0.0776112 , 0.48593384, 0.43645496]])
```

The maximum in each row is:

```
In [47]: np.max(arr, axis=1)                                                    
Out[47]: array([0.51249827, 0.51152126, 0.48593384])
```

Its row index is:

```
In [48]: np.argmax(arr, axis=1)                                                 
Out[48]: array([1, 1, 1])
```

We can map that `argmax` array onto a array with the same shape with:

```
In [52]: x = np.zeros(arr.shape, int)                                           
In [53]: x[np.arange(3),_48] = 1                                                
In [54]: x                                                                      
Out[54]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```